# Good introductory books on the philosophy of art

Tags: aesthetics, art

I’ve been reading around a bit on the function of art and found several: aesthetic expression (Wilde the preface to a picture of Dorian Grey), self-exploration, social commentary, moral values (Tolstory what is art), provocation etc; and reading further, I found that this topic comes under the philosophy of art.

This is an area I’ve never really gone in to so, I’d be interested in an introductory text that discusses these ideas and any others.

Given this is a new area, I wouldn’t mind suggestions on other areas to look in, as I don’t feel certain if the philosophy of art is the right place to be looking.

Comment: Possibly https://www.cambridge.org/de/universitypress/subjects/philosophy/philosophy-general-interest/introduction-philosophy-art-2nd-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781107614444